# The most efficient way to access a mysql database extracting multiple data for website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a classified ads page, i'm using mysql with php.
my ads table as a simplified form is something like:

```
ad id -> int
ad title -> text
ad description  -> text
ad description  -> text
ad type -> boolean (if 0 is a private add, if is 1 is abusiness ad)
ad op -> boolean  if zero is a used item if 1 is a new item)
```

What I whant is to **get the number of private and public ads**
and the **number of used and new items** without making 4 calls to the database, is that even possible?

Right now I'm making 5 calls, since I show 20 ads per page
my calls to the database are:

1. get the data of the **20 ads** using select * table.... LIMIT 1,20
2. count the number of **private** adds using num_rows;
3. count the number of **business** adds using num_rows;
4. count the number of **used adds** using num_rows;
5. count the number of **new adds** using num_rows;

Is there some method to do the same but with less calls to the database ?

Comment: I whant to get the **total** number of private and businesse ads and the **total** number of new and used item ads

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: From what you're saying, the best option here, would be to use a caching system that refreshes once you have new data in the database, thus avoiding any new queries to the database until data is updated/added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge last 4 points into one single query, using [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) with [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(IF (`type` = 0, id, NULL)) AS private_ads_count, 
  COUNT(IF (`type` = 1, id, NULL)) AS business_ads_count, 
  COUNT(IF (`op` = 0, id, NULL)) AS used_ads_count, 
  COUNT(IF (`op` = 1, id, NULL)) AS new_ads_count
FROM ads_table
```

**Alternate** approach is using [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function with [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF (`type` = 0, 1, 0)) AS private_ads_count, 
  SUM(IF (`type` = 1, 1, 0)) AS business_ads_count, 
  SUM(IF (`op` = 0, 1, 0)) AS used_ads_count, 
  SUM(IF (`op` = 1, 1, 0)) AS new_ads_count
FROM ads_table
```

**Note** that `type` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T), so we need use backticks (`) around it.

Comment: thanks  but i get this error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type = 0, id, NULL) AS private_ads_count, **

Comment: @AnaPaulaGomesPaula type is a reserved keyword. Editing my answer. We need use backticks.

Comment: @AnaPaulaGomesPaula please use the edited answer now.

Comment: I found the Problem it was missing ( )  on if  **COUNT( IF (type= 0, id, NULL) )**

Comment: @AnaPaulaGomesPaula ok good. Consider marking this answer as accepted (green tick); if it helped you :)

Comment: other thing it help if you whant to get the values on php 
 `$count = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 echo $count['business_ads_count'];`